# How to iterate after some data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a product model with has_many images model

so on the first loop i just get the first 4 images

```
 <%  @product.images.first(4).each do |i| %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%= i.photo.url.to_s %>">
        <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:small).to_s, :class => 'thumbnail circle', :'data-zoom-href' => i.photo.url(:big).to_s) %>
      </a>
    </li>
       <% end %>
```

**how to loop the rest of images after the first 4 images?**

*i've tried this: without sucess!*

```
 <ul>


  <%  @product.images.last.each do |i| %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%= i.photo.url.to_s %>">
        <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:small).to_s, :class => 'thumbnail circle', :'data-zoom-href' => i.photo.url(:big).to_s) %>
      </a>
    </li>
       <% end %>


  </ul>
```

Comment: Try `@product.images.in_groups_of(4).each do |i|` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset`:

```
@product.images.offset(4).each { }
```

`offset(4)` means all records after first 4.